# how can i get the object not map address?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm try to connect java spring boot with mysql. when i run the code i got the map address like this

This is my first code

This is EmpController1

```
package com.example.rest.controller;


import com.example.rest.repository.R1pro;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.example.rest.repository.EmpRepository1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/emp")
@Slf4j
public class EmpController1 {
    @Autowired
    private EmpRepository1 empRepository1;
    @RequestMapping(value="/ee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getCategoryList() {
        List<String> sj = new ArrayList<String>();
        Gson gson= new Gson();
        System.out.println(123);
        List<R1pro> emps1 = this.empRepository1.findByLimit();


        return emps1.toString();
    }
}
```

This is my EmpRepository1 code

```
package com.example.rest.repository;
import com.example.rest.Emp;
import com.example.rest.Emp1;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface EmpRepository1 extends JpaRepository<Emp1, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "select * from d_RANGE limit 1",nativeQuery = true)
    public List<R1pro> findByLimit();
}
```

This is R1pro code

```
package com.example.rest.repository;

import java.util.Date;


public interface R1pro {
    public String USER_ID();
    public String CUST_GP();
}
```

This is my Emp1 code

```
package com.example.rest;


import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TEMP_TEST_M78_2W")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Emp1 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String USER_ID;
    private String CUST_GP;
}
```

This is my Application code

```
package com.example.rest;
import com.example.rest.repository.EmpRepository;
import com.example.rest.repository.EmpRepository1;
import com.example.rest.repository.R1pro;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class Application {
    @Autowired
    EmpRepository empRepository;
    @Autowired
    EmpRepository1 empRepository1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner start() {
        return args -> {mysql();};
    }


    private void mysql() {
        List<R1pro> emp1 = this.empRepository1.findByLimit();
    }
}
```

When i run the code i got this result

```
[org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap@27ae5583]
```

So i change the EmpController1 code

```
package com.example.rest.controller;


import com.example.rest.repository.R1pro;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.example.rest.repository.EmpRepository1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/emp")
@Slf4j
public class EmpController1 {
    @Autowired
    private EmpRepository1 empRepository1;
    @RequestMapping(value="/ee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getCategoryList() {
        List<String> sj = new ArrayList<String>();
        Gson gson= new Gson();
        System.out.println(123);
        List<R1pro> emps1 = this.empRepository1.findByLimit();

        for (int i =0; i<emps1.size();i++)
        {
            sj.add(emps1.get(i).USER_ID()+" "+ emps1.get(i).CUST_GP());
        }

        return sj.toString();
    }
}
```

When i run the code i got this Error message

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invoked method public abstract java.lang.String com.example.rest.repository.R1pro.USER_ID() is no accessor method!
```

Actually this method same as mysql data columns

```
USER_ID varchar(150) 
CUST_GP varchar(1)
```

This is my sql columns informations

I don't know what is the problem also any solution.. so if someone knows that please teach me
I really admire to solve this issue

thank you!

Comment: Why are you getting `List<R1pro>`, try `List<Emp1>`.

Comment: where?!? please say that intensive

Comment: Your repository is on Emp1 not on R1pro. Change this line: `List<R1pro> emps1 = this.empRepository1.findByLimit();`

Comment: Error:(30, 59) java: incompatible types: java.util.List<com.example.rest.repository.R1pro> cannot be converted to java.util.List<com.example.rest.Emp1>

Comment: it's wrong answer it..

Comment: change this in the repository also: `public List<R1pro> findByLimit();` to Emp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tweak your interface into something like this -

```
public interface R1pro {
    String getUSER_ID();
    String getCUST_GP();
}
```

The resultset is mapped only to the getter methods similar to the one created in **Emp1** class

Comment: raised same issue

Comment: Could you confirm if lombok has created the getters and setters properly. Lombok could treat the _ in fieldname differently while creating getters and setters unless you are using @Accessors(fluent = true)